# Using UtteranceProgressListener in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin, and have been playing with the Android [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) class recently.  I got it working in a rudimentary way, but now I want to try detecting when the speaking has started/stopped.

As I understand it, I need to use an [UtteranceProgressListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html), but I can't quite see how to set this up in Kotlin.  Here's the method where I'm setting this up:

```
private fun setTextToSpeech() {
    textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(this@PhraseListActivity, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            val languageToSpeak = Locale(intent.getStringExtra(DESIRED_LOCALE))
            val result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(languageToSpeak)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                toast("This language is not supported for text-to-speech")
            } else {
                languageCanBeSpoken = true
            }
        } else
            Log.e("error", "Initilisation Failed!")
    })

    class speechListener : UtteranceProgressListener() {
        override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
            toast("finished speaking")
        }

        override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {
            toast("error when speaking")
        }

        override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
            toast("speaking started")
        }

    }

    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(speechListener)
}
```

The line that starts `textToSpeech =` works ok, but the last line in the function that attempts to set the utterance listener doesn't work.  When I try to set the `speechListener` via `textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener` it's giving me a compilation error :

> Classifier 'speechListener' does not have a companion object and must
>   be initialized here

I'm not too sure whether it's asking for something in the companion object in `speechListener`, or some other initialisation, any ideas?

Comment: Change `class speechListener` to `val speechListener = object :`

Comment: thanks for the comment @yole , but I'm not too sure I understand.  I think I need to extend the abstract Java class UtteranceProgressListener and override the methods?  I tried doing as you suggested, but it didn't compile, but probably I misunderstood.  Sorry if I'm being dense, and thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `class speechListener` declaration in your code declares a local class. The `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` requires an instance of the class as a parameter. Therefore, you need to call the constructor to create the instance:

```
textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(speechListener())
```

Alternatively, you can use an [object expression](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), which is an equivalent of Java's anonymous inner class:

```
val speechListener = object : UtteranceProgressListener() { ... }
textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(speechListener)
```